# Chernoff bound multiplicative forms

Tags: probability, inequality

I encountered a form of Chernoff bound in Vapnik's book "Statistical Learning Theory" as follows:

$$P\left\{ \frac{p - v_l}{\sqrt{p}} \right\} < \exp\left\{ \frac{-\epsilon^2 l}{2} \right\}$$

$$P\left\{ \frac{v_l - p}{\sqrt{p}} \right\} < \exp\left\{ \frac{-\epsilon^2 l}{3} \right\}$$

The author claims that the above inequalities are equivalent to the following:

$$P\{ v_l < (1 - \gamma) p \} < \exp\left\{ \frac{-\gamma^2 pl }{2} \right\}$$
$$P\{ v_l > (1 + \gamma) p \} < \exp\left\{ \frac{-\gamma^2 pl}{3} \right\}$$

Can anyone show me how to transform from one form to the other?

Comment: $\epsilon$ is missing on the LHS of the first set of equations. Also, define the quantities: $v_l,p,l$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your LHS for the first equations is $P\left\{\frac{p-v_l}{\sqrt{p}}>\epsilon\right\}$, we have
\begin{equation}
P\left\{\frac{p-v_l}{\sqrt{p}}>\epsilon\right\} = P\left\{v_l<p-\epsilon\sqrt{p}\right\} = P\left\{v_l<\left(1-\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{p}}\right)p\right\}.
\end{equation}
Since $\gamma=\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{p}} $, substituting $\epsilon = \gamma\sqrt{p}$ in the first equation, we get the third equation. Similarly, we can obtain the fourth equation.